# best way to parse nested object in AngularJS?

Tags: json, angularjs, object, nested

I'm trying to use angularjs for parsing a nested data structure returned from a remote server. I'm really stumped by this pattern because i'm trying to access the "events" data with the following function

```
$scope.generate_event = function(){
            from_date = $scope.dts.from
            to_date = $scope.dts.to

            from = from_date.getFullYear()+'/'+(from_date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+from_date.getDate()
            to = to_date.getFullYear()+'/'+(to_date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+to_date.getDate()
            $http.get(server+'rawdata?vids='+$scope.selected_vehicle.id+'&evfields=lat,lon,f_event_time,speed&from='+from+'&to='+to)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.report_data = data
                $localStorage.report_data = data
                $scope.generate()
            })
        }
```

Any advice or even a hint on the best approach would be great, i need this running for work and its been a month now. Thanks!

```
{
"rawData": {
    "keys": {
        "lat": ["number", "lat"],
        "lon": ["number", "lon"],
        "speed": ["number", "Speed [mph]"],
        "code": ["number", "EVC"],
        "vid": ["number", "Vehicle ID"]
    },
    "keys_order": ["lat", "lon", "speed", "code", "vid"],
    "events": [{
        "f_lon": -8.3315599999999996,
        "code": 4,
        "vid": 5,
        "lon": -833156,
        "f_lat": 51.90831,
        "lat": 5190831,
        "speed": 78.0
    }, {
        "f_lon": -8.3741599999999998,
        "code": 4,
        "vid": 5,
        "lon": -837416,
        "f_lat": 51.903979999999997,
        "lat": 5190398,
        "speed": 78.0
    }]
}
```

}

UPDATE: I didnt explain the problem correctly. Here's the generate function

```
$scope.generate = function(){
            $scope.event_config = {
                title: 'Events',    // chart title, legend etc
            /*etc
             *etc
             */
            data = {}
            data.series = ['&nbsp;Events']
            data.data = []
 this fucker ----->$scope.report_data.events.forEach(function(value, index, array){
                o = {}
                o.x = value.f_event_time
                o.y = [value.lat+'/'+value.lon]
                o.tooltip = value.speed
                data.data.push(o)
            })
            $scope.event_data = data
```

I'm getting error 'forEach undefined'. This is supposed to generate a d3 chart but 'report_data' is intially used to store distance data from a different function for local storage. So do i need a second variable for localStorage? ie $scope.report_event = $localStorage.report_event? Can someone look at the source code if i send it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get(server+'rawdata?vids='+$scope.selected_vehicle.id+'&evfields=lat,lon,f_event_time,speed&from='+from+'&to='+to)
            .success(function(data){
                if (data) {
                   var events = data.rawData.events; // get the events json array
                   $scope.generate(events);
                }
            })
```

and in your controller have the declarative function like

```
$scope.generate = function(events) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: time for a stupid question......

can i pass that events var into my $scope.generate function?

Comment: Sure, I edited my previous post to show you how to do

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following

```
$scope.generate_report = function(){
            from_date = $scope.dts.from
            to_date = $scope.dts.to

            from = from_date.getFullYear()+'/'+(from_date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+from_date.getDate()
            to = to_date.getFullYear()+'/'+(to_date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+to_date.getDate()
            $http.get(server+'vehicle/'+$scope.selected_vehicle.id+'/counters/deltas/day?from='+from+'&to='+to)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.report_data = data
                $localStorage.report_data = data
                $scope.process()
            })
            $http.get(server+'rawdata?vids='+$scope.selected_vehicle.id+'&genevcodes=39,40&evfields=lat,lon,f_event_time,mph,speed,code&from='+from+'&to='+to)
            .success(function(data){
                if(data){
                    var events = data.rawData.events
                }
                $scope.report_event = events
                $localStorage.report_event = events
                $scope.generate()
            })
        }
```

just had to declare another localstorage variable for storing events from the JSON object Thanks Yannik